# I am using @react-pdf/render in my react project website want to render it as HTML in react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, react-pdfrenderer

i have my html data coming from backend and need to render thr html content in react-pdf

i have tried out using <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
and it is not rendering any content and showing blank pdf